# Use Wix Installer to install a service.

Tags: service, wix, installation

everyone, I'm using Wix to make an installer to run a service, below are my problems:

I use a custom action to call sc.exe to install and start the service, then I use custom action to call sc.exe [stop/delete] to remove the service when uninstall. This works fine except that a messagebox says

```
"The setup must update files or services that cannot be updated while the system is running, if you choose to continue, a reboot will be required to complete the setup"
```

But in fact after I click "OK", no reboot happened, and the service uninstalled successfully, how can I get rid of this message box?

Another problem is that, after click "OK" in the message box, another messagebox will pop up and tells me that "Another program has exclusive access to file [fileA], please click retry", and after I click retry, the uninstall finished successfully. [fileA] has been removed, but another file [fildB] was left behind.

but I do use a component :

```
<Component
  <RemoveFile ..
  <RemoveFile ...
</Component>
```

to remove these files. and I have

```
<Custom Action="StopService" Before="RemoveFiles">..
<Custom Action="RemoveService" After="StopService>..
```

In my wix . 
Anyone has some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like service may not have actually shut down by the time Windows is trying to delete it or handles or process are still open to it may be for this reason its prompting for that massage box requiring a reboot to delete.
Windows can't uninstall a service if there are process/handles open to it.
In present scenerio after reboot i guess it will delete remaining files.
Try providing wait in your Custom Action for stop and remove service Provide **asyncWait** in **return** tag.
It might Solve your problem.
You are using SC.exe to control service via. custom action instead of this i recommend you to use WIX **ServiceControl** element.

Comment: going through log might be useful it will give you a better picture of the files involved and whether the in-use is detected at InstallValidate time or at file removal time.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice, but the action's return is already "asyncWait". I'll go through the logs to see where goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the StopService and RemoveService custom actions before the costing standard actions, this is where Windows Installer analyzes to see what resources are in use and decides it if will prompt the user with the mentioned message box or not.